# C# to VB.NET conversion

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have C# code, but while converting it to vb.net (using online convertor) is giving me error.

C# code is :

```
await client.SendAsync(new TLI() {user_id = user.id}, "MESSAGE");
```

and the converted code is :

```
Await client.SendAsync(New TLI() With {Key .user_id = user.id}, "MESSAGE")
```

what is Key in the converted code. vb.net say it an error. Can anyone explain me the concept?

Comment: Convert.Net converts it to: `Await client.SendAsync(New TLI() With { .user_id = user.id}, "MESSAGE")`

Comment: Just remove `Key`. `Await client.SendAsync(New TLI() With {.user_id = user.id}, "MESSAGE")`

Comment: Remove the word `Key`. Not sure why it's been popped in, I would say it's not required in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types#key-properties) is used in VB.NET to tell the compiler what properties are the key-properties in anonymous types that are used in `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. This feature doesn't exist in C# where every property is a "key".

Since that is not an anonymous type is is a bug of the converter. This works:

```
Await client.SendAsync(New TLI() With {.user_id = user.id}, "MESSAGE")
```

Comment: @KodeeswaranDuraisamy: then consider to accept it :)